# Packed Unions in SystemVerilog

Tags: oop, enums, system-verilog, unions

The code is not too long so I am posting the complete code.

```
// Code your design here
module temp;
typedef enum logic[15:0]
{
  ADD = 16'h0000,
  SUB = 16'h0001
} my_opcode_t;

typedef enum logic[15:0]
{
  REG = 16'h0000,
  MEM = 16'h0001
} my_dest_t;
  
  typedef struct packed
{
  my_opcode_t  opcode; // 16-bit opcode, enumerated type
  my_dest_t    dest; // 16-bit destination, enumerated type
  logic [15:0] opA;
  logic [15:0] opB;
} my_opcode_struct_t;

my_opcode_struct_t cmd1;
  
  
typedef union packed
{
  my_opcode_struct_t opcode_s; //"fields view" to the struct
  logic[1:0][31:0] dword; // "dword view" to the struct
} my_opcode_union_t;

my_opcode_union_t cmd2;

initial begin
  $display("cmd1 = %p",cmd1);
  $display("cmd2 = %p", cmd2);
  // Access opcode_s struct fields within the union
  cmd2.opcode_s.opcode = ADD;
  cmd2.opcode_s.dest = REG;
  cmd2.opcode_s.opA = 16'h0001;
  cmd2.opcode_s.opB = 16'h0002;
  $display("cmd1 = %p",cmd1);
  $display("cmd2 = %p", cmd2);

  // Access dwords struct fields within the union
  cmd2.dword[1] = 32'h0001_0001; // opcode=SUB, dest=MEM
  cmd2.dword[0] = 32'h0007_0008; // opA=7, opB=8
  $display("cmd2 = %p", cmd2);
  end
endmodule
```

Source: https://www.verilogpro.com/systemverilog-structures-unions-design/

Output:

[image]

I ran this code in EDA playground. I did not understand why is it showing"

`cmd2='{opcode_s:'{opcode:SUB, dest:MEM, opA:'h7,opB:'h8}}`

I was expecting, it would print dword values.
What is it missing in my understanding about unions?
Is it because we are not using `cmd2.dword[0]` or `cmd2.dword[1]` it is printing some garbage values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you do not print `dword` values is due to the behavior of the `%p` format specifier.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 21.2.1.7 *Assignment pattern format*:

> The %p format specifier may be used to print aggregate expressions
> such as unpacked structures, arrays, and unions. ... For unions, only
> the first declared elements shall be printed.

If you change your `union` declaration as follows (with `dword` first):

```
typedef union packed
{
  logic[1:0][31:0] dword; // "dword view" to the struct
  my_opcode_struct_t opcode_s; //"fields view" to the struct
} my_opcode_union_t;
```

you will see this output:

```
cmd1 = '{opcode:'hxxxx, dest:'hxxxx, opA:'hxxxx, opB:'hxxxx}
cmd2 = '{dword:'hxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx}
cmd1 = '{opcode:'hxxxx, dest:'hxxxx, opA:'hxxxx, opB:'hxxxx}
cmd2 = '{dword:'h10002}
cmd2 = '{dword:'h1000100070008}
```